# Maximize/minimize buttons on the title bar does not show in a dialog based a MFC project

Tags: mfc

I have created a dialog based simple application in MFC using VS10. In the properties box of the dialog window I have selected system menu as true, maximize box as true, minimize box as true still during run time I don't see any maximize or minimize button on the tittle bar. Why this thing happens and how to make the maximize/minimize button visible and active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the title bar appear at all?

Make sure Tool Window is false.

Comment: You are just great................maybe I am not a pro...but still I think you are great.............thank you very much.........